# "role" value with DOM Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have to insert this HTML code with Javascript DOM:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

But i don't understand how to insert the value : role="progressbar" in a DOM function.
Anybody can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Call `.setAttribute("role", "progressbar")` on the element.

Comment: So how are you creating the elmement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try out the Javscript below and see the output in console**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const progressBar=document.querySelector(".progress-bar");

  progressBar.setAttribute('role',"progressbar");

  console.log(progressBar);
});
```

Comment: I hope this will help you!